# Google Cloud Function - SendGrid - 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I'm trying to send an email using SendGrid in my Google Cloud Function. I have my key in the Firebase environment variables, so that's present.

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

Here is my GCF .ts code:

**Code**

```
const msg = {
    to: to,
    from: from,
    subject: 'Email Subject',
    content: [{
        type: "text/html",
        value: body
    }]
};

await sgMail.send(msg)
    .then(r => {
        console.log(r);
    });
```

When I trigger the function and check my logs, this is the error I get:

**Error**

```
error:  { Error: Bad Request
    at ResponseError (node_modules/@sendgrid/mail/node_modules/@sendgrid/helpers/classes/response-error.js:19:5)
    at Request.http [as _callback] (node_modules/@sendgrid/mail/node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:124:25)
    at Request.self.callback (node_modules/@sendgrid/mail/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/@sendgrid/mail/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/@sendgrid/mail/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
code: 400,
message: 'Bad Request',
response: 
{ headers: 
    { server: 'nginx',
        date: 'Sun, 16 Dec 2018 16:27:56 GMT',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'content-length': '402',
        connection: 'close',
        'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
        'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
        'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
        'access-control-max-age': '600',
        'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html' },
    body: { errors: [Object] } } }
```

Does anyone have any familiarity with this error? It mentions CORS, but that makes no sense, because it's a cloud function, not browser. The SendGrid API isn't that great, it mostly goes over the field names and provides no examples. Thanks for any help provided!

***EDIT***

Just to update the question, in the front end response I send myself I found a different error than the `console.log(error)` in the GCF logs:

```
"Email failed: Bad Request (400)
The from object must be provided for every email send. 
It is an object that requires the email parameter, 
but may also contain a name 
parameter.  e.g. {"email" : "example@example.com"}  or 
{"email" : "example@example.com", "name" : "Example Recipient"}.
    from.email
    http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.from"
```

***EDIT 2: SOLUTION***

My from email source comes from a document in Firestore, and I was trying to get a field that didn't exist because I was querying the wrong document, therefore `from` was `undefined`. Corrected it, as well as removed "content" in the `msg` object per the suggestion / answer below, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-nodejs-code-example/) ...the `msg` has the wrong elements:

```
const sg = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sg.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const msg = {
    to: 'test@example.com',
    from: 'test@example.com',
    subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
    text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
    html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};

sg.send(msg).then(() => {
    /* assume success */
})
.catch(error => {

    /* log friendly error */
    console.error(error.toString());

    /* extract error message */
    const {message, code, response} = error;

    /* extract response message */
    const {headers, body} = response;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, nice find on that documentation. I changed to that format. I did, however, find a new error that I put at the bottom of an updated question. So, I'm investigating. I'll keep this Q/A updated.

Comment: Hahah, I had a malformed db call to the wrong document in Firestore, therefore my "from" was undefined. But, I also probably needed the format for `text` and `html` you posted above. Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: @Kenny not certain about it, but one possibly has to follow a format alike `email: {"email": "example@example.com"}` for the property names. the whole error codes somehow all use the same example. https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html there's also a troubleshooting guide: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md (the source code might also show how the `msg` object & properties need to look alike)